# How to push elements of an object into another object?

Tags: javascript, object, push

Like in arrays we can add new elements by using array`.push(item)`. How to do the same with `objects`? And can it be done inside the object? Like:

```
var myObject={apple: "a", orange: "o"};
var anothObject = {lemon: "l", myObject};
```

Comment: Do you want all the properties of the object or just some?

Comment: I want to add all of them to the other object

Comment: Try looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's extend function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend( object1, object2 );
```

Answer (score 11):

To copy all elements of one object to another object, use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var myObject = { apple: "a", orange: "o" };
var anothObject = Object.assign( { lemon: "l" }, myObject );
```

Or, more elegantly ES6 style using [spread `...` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
let myObject = { apple: "a", orange: "o" };
let anothObject = { lemon: "l", ...myObject };
```

Answer (score 7):

You could add some properties of an object simply like this :

```
obj = {a : "1", b : "2"};

myObj = {c: "3", d : "4"};
myObj.a = obj.a;
myObj.b = obj.b;
```

**Update**:

In that case just do this :

```
for(var prop in obj) myObj[prop] = obj[prop];
```

And to filter out the unwanted properties inside the loop body you could also do this :

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        myObj[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would take forever to do this with the object I have which has about 100 properties.

Answer (score 1):

A non-jquery option: you could iterate of the keys of the object to be merged.

```
var myObject={apple: "a", orange: "o"};
var anothObject = {lemon: "l"};

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
    anothObject[key] = myObject[key];
});
```

At the end of the loop `anothObject` is `{lemon: "l", apple: "a", orange: "o"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject={apple: "a", orange: "o"};
myObject.lemon = 1; // myObject is now {apple: "a", orange: "o", lemon: 1}
```

Comment: I have an object with about 100 properties. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

```
var addToObject = function (obj, key, value, index) {

// Create a temp object and index variable
var temp = {};
var i = 0;

// Loop through the original object
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

        // If the indexes match, add the new item
        if (i === index && key && value) {
            temp[key] = value;
        }

        // Add the current item in the loop to the temp obj
        temp[prop] = obj[prop];

        // Increase the count
        i++;

    }
}

// If no index, add to the end
if (!index && key && value) {
    temp[key] = value;
}

return temp;

};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `jQuery.extend()` function

```
var myObject={apple: "a", orange: "o"};
var anothObject = {lemon: "l"};

jQuery.extend(myObject, anothObject);
console.log(myObject);
```